# UIScrollView ContentOffset not Reaching Edge of Screen

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, uiscrollview, uiscrollviewdelegate

I'm having a problem with `UIScrollView`, not sure if it's a bug or not, but it's occurring when I implement a `UIScrollView` with its `delegate` and a zoomable / pannable image.

First off, when I pan the image, it's possible that the `contentOffset` can be a non integer value (.5). For certain `zoomScales`, when I pan the image all the way to the edge, it's falling a half pixel shy of reaching the edge because of this.

It's a very small thing, but in my app I have to drag objects around the screen, and if I drag an object to the corner, you can notice it.

I've implemented the following to try and correct the problem and make it so the `contentOffset` has to be a whole value:

```
- (void)scrollViewWillEndDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView withVelocity:(CGPoint)velocity targetContentOffset:(inout CGPoint *)targetContentOffset
{
    if (targetContentOffset->x != ceilf(targetContentOffset->x))
    {
        if (velocity.x > 0)
        {
            targetContentOffset->x = ceilf(targetContentOffset->x);
        }
        else 
        {
            targetContentOffset->x = floorf(targetContentOffset->x);
        }
    }

    if (targetContentOffset->y != ceilf(targetContentOffset->y))
    {
        if (velocity.y > 0)
        {
            targetContentOffset->y = ceilf(targetContentOffset->y);
        }
        else 
        {
            targetContentOffset->y = floorf(targetContentOffset->y);
        }
    }
}
```

However, it doesn't seem to be working as my `targetContentOffset` is completely different than the `contentOffset` property.

Does anyone a) why this bug is occurring or b) how to fix it using the above delegate method or some other means?

Comment: Hmm, you're right. This seems like it should work. I deleted my answer, and learned something new in the process.

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively this method implementation may work for you also.

```
-(void)scrollViewDidEndScrollingAnimation:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
```

Looking at your comments below, you may have to implement multiple methods.  The one above or the one stated in the other answer post for when it slows to a stop, just to make sure you touch your edge condition, and the method you already have to process for the velocity points.

Comment: Also try scrollViewDidEndDecelerating if necessary, and/or scrollViewDidScroll...just set the content offset to a new value, not animated.